# Pastebin が常に 422 を返す

Tags: node.js, typescript, webapi

### 問題

Pastebin にアカウント登録をし、APIを使おうとしていたのですが、
`Bad API request, invalid api_dev_key` と出て一向に成功する気配がありません。
APIキーに空白は含まれていないし、[ページ](https://pastebin.com/doc_api)からコピーしたので間違うわけがありません。

### コード

```
import * as qs from 'querystring'
import * as fetch from 'node-fetch'

～～～

const query = qs.stringify({
  api_option: 'paste',
  api_dev_key: 'こぴーしてきたAPIかぎ',
  api_paste_name: `たいとる`,
  api_paste_format: 'javascript',
  api_paste_code: 'こーど',
})

const url = await (
  await fetch.default(`https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php?${query}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
).text()

console.log(url)
```

#### 期待していた結果

`https://pastebin.com/xxxxxx`

#### 実際の結果

`Bad API request, invalid api_dev_key`

Comment: `method: POST` とされていますが、その形式は `HTTP GET` に見えます。`POST` の場合は `body` パラメータに `${query}` を指定するのではないでしょうか。`

Answer (score 1):

> `method: POST` とされていますが、その形式は `HTTP GET` に見えます。`POST` の場合は `body` パラメータに `${query}` を指定するのではないでしょうか。`

[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さん、ありがとうございました。
その通りでした。`body` に渡すことで解決しました。